# Play! framework: HTTPS and HTTP at the same time

Tags: playframework

I added `https.port` to my `application.conf` to gain HTTPS support. The problem is one of my routes require to be accessible through HTTP because the client is not supporting HTTPS. Is it somehow possible to make this happen without having to disable HTTPS for the whole site.

Thanks.

Edit:

My route file is pretty standard and has not changed since I converted to HTTPS. The problem is when I want to connect to the HTTP port, my connection times out.

Comment: Why are you not able to use both right now? What's the problem? What is in your routes file?

Answer (score 7):

You just need to have both http.port and https.port in the application.conf file.  For the links you want to be different from the normal site, use the @@ notation:

`@@{Controller.action().secure()} => https://...`

@@{Controller.action()} => http://

Comment: How do you force some routes to be available only in https? For example the login page

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 2.0.

In my case `@routes.Application.authenticate().absoluteURL(secure = true)` generates *https* prefixed url, thought it's not working since I didn't fully configure it yet.

In prod I'm planning to use reverse proxy anyways.